# TypeScript: Get difference between two dates in days

Tags: typescript

I need to get the difference between two dates in days.

Up to now, I've been able to get the difference between two dates, but not in days:

```
date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I strongly believe this question is not duplicate to attached.
The attached question/answer gives different between two dates in years/months/days, but this question is different between two dates in days only.

The below answer by @mohammad works.

Comment: The date-fns library's differenceInDays function is good for this https://date-fns.org/docs/differenceInDays

Answer (score 82):

```
var date1 = new Date(2023, 1, 1);
var date2 = new Date(2023, 2, 1);
var diff = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
console.log("Diff in Days: " + diffDays);
```

Comment: This will work with daylight savings as well?

Comment: no, it won't work with daylight savings

Answer (score 17):

I believe the shortest route is:

```
var diff = date1.valueOf() - date2.valueOf();
```

Comment: I am not sure that is entirely correct by itself, I think you still need to do the diffDays calculation from the other answer. But it is correct you can replace the first statement in the other answer with what you suggest.